# API works in postman but not working in HTTP client call

Tags: c#, http-status-code-400

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateOTP(string Mobile)
{
    try
    {
        StringContent jsonstr = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Mobile = Mobile }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        endPoint = _httpClient.BaseAddress + "User/OTPGenerate";
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(endPoint, jsonstr);
        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return Content(response.Content.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("apifail");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Content(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This is my code for a call to the API but the response is "error 400 bad request".
I allow all header types in API using cros policy.

I expecting 200 success code.

Comment: What returns 400? The request to GenerateOTP or the request to OTPGenerate? If the second, the call is *definitely* bad. `PostAsJsonAsync` will serialize any object to a JSON string and post it. It's there so you don't have to do this yourself

Comment: Have you tried having Postman generate C# code?

Comment: What does the error response contain? Quite possibly it already explains what's wrong, eg a missing property. There's a standard way to report validation errors as 400 responses defined in RFC7807 and ASP.NET Core implements it

Comment: There's no need for `_httpClient.BaseAddress + "User/OTPGenerate";` either. The BaseAddress is prepended to any relative URL already. You should be able to write just `var response=await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("User/OTPGenerate",new{Mobile=Mobile});`

Comment: OTPGenerate responce is 400 with this code

Comment: response=await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("User/OTPGenerate",new{Mobile=Mobile}); also same error comming

Comment: @ODR_MUNA: Does the response content contain any information about *why* it considers the request to be bad?  Can you reach out to whoever maintains that server to provide any additional information?

Comment: This sort of problem come up a lot, and the solution is simple: capture both HTTP requests (e.g. using Fiddler) and compare them.